# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '.03' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have made a query to calculate minutes in hours that was not done yet, unfortunately I got that error.  Also can some one please tell me how can I convert minutes in hours, e.g 1.45hr should equal 1.75hr , 1.30 should be 1.5 and then I want to add them.

```
SELECT  * ,
        ( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)), 1, 1) ) AS Hours ,
        ( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)), 3, 4) ) AS Minutes ,
        ( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)), 3, 4) * 10 / 60.00 ) AS FractionalHours ,
        ROUND(( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)), 3, 4) * 10 / 60.00 ) / 10 + ( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)), 1, 1) ), 2) AS ActualHours
FROM    WorkDone
WHERE   NoOfHoursWorked LIKE '%.%' 
  ------- UpDate----
UPDATE  WorkDone
SET     NoOfHoursWorked = ROUND(( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)),  3, 4) * 10 / 60.00 ) / 10
                                + ( SUBSTRING(CAST(( NoOfHoursWorked ) AS VARCHAR(500)),1, 1) ), 2)
```

Comment: What does your NoOfHoursWorkedactually look like?

Comment: can you share sample data for `NoOfHoursWorked` column?

Comment: Not able to put image here data is like this 1.30 or 1.3 , 1.50 ,2,3.50  these are hours before decimal and after that are minutes

Comment: You would be a lot better off storing the number of minutes worked than the number of hours, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Samad :  and you want to add these decimals such that it give you output like 1.30 + 1.50 + 2.00 + 3.50 = `9.10`?

Comment: @Deepak: Yes exactly please tell me the formula or trick to solve it, if minutes i calculate seperatly it can b done, but with hours how it will b?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a float Value to Time in sql and get its sum?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883574/how-do-i-convert-a-float-value-to-time-in-sql-and-get-its-sum)

Answer (score 1):

You have this expression:

```
SUBSTRING(cast((NoOfHoursWorked) as varchar(500)),3,4)*10/60.00
------------------------------------------------------
```

You are multiplying a substring by integers.  I have no idea what `NoOfHoursWorked` is.  It would seem strange to me if this were stored as anything other than a numeric.  So, perhaps this will work:

```
NoOfHoursWorked*10/60.00
```

If you do need the strange string manipulations, just convert the result to a number:

```
cast(SUBSTRING(cast((NoOfHoursWorked) as varchar(500)),3,4) as float) *10/60.00)
```

Comment: NoOfHoursWorked is hours inserted by employees in decimal formate.

Comment: @Samad . . . Then the first answer should work.  There is no need to convert it to a string to do arithmetic.  In fact, such a conversion seems awkward, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add these decimals such that it give you output like 1.30 + 1.50 + 2.00 + 3.50 = 9.10
then this might be helpful :

```
-- if your column is decimal(x,2)
SELECT  sum(CAST(NoOfHoursWorked as int))
+ sum(cast(Parsename(NoOfHoursWorked,1) as int))/60 
+ (sum(cast(Parsename(NoOfHoursWorked,1) as int))%60) *0.01
FROM    yourtable 

-- if your column is float or decimal(x,2)
SELECT  sum(CAST(NoOfHoursWorked as int))
+ sum(cast(Parsename(cast((NoOfHoursWorked) as decimal(10,2)),1) as int))/60 
+ (sum(cast(Parsename(cast((NoOfHoursWorked) as decimal(10,2)),1) as int))%60) *0.01
FROM    yourtable
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/569e2/1) for first query.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/853ef4/1) for second query.

NOTE : *I found same question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26883574/how-do-i-convert-a-float-value-to-time-in-sql-and-get-its-sum/26884396#26884396)**. There are other answers too for same thing. check that out.*